# Drag & drop to change order of controls in windows forms panel

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop, custom-controls, panel

I have a windows forms application that contains a panel to which multiple instances of a custom control can be added, with each one being docked with DockStyle.Top.

This results in a fixed top to bottom order.

I'd like to be able to re-order the controls within the panel, ideally drag and drop, but using an up/down arrow for each control would suffice.

I do not need to alter the X axis co-ordinates of the controls, only the y-axis vertical order of the controls.

Is this type of drag and drop possible?
What is the best way to achieve what I want.

Comment: check out this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-performing-a-drag-and-drop-operation-in-windows-forms

Answer (score -1):

Order of controls Docked to top is the same as their order in form's Controls collection.
You can try reordering them there in runtime.